# rsync to create a backup directory everyday

Tags: rsync

CentOS 5.3
    subverion 1.4.2

I am using rsync to backup a repository every day at midnight. We have about 30 repositories some small and some large.

I am using crontab to schedule the job that will run the script file.

The script will have to recursively go through each directory:

```
repos/DEV/
         /repso1
         /repso2
     DOCS/
         /repso3
etc
```

On the target machine I want to create a new directory with the date the backup was done.

i.e.

```
backup/09OCT2010
      /10OCT2010
      /11OCT2010
```

So far I have been experimenting with this:

```
rsync -virza --backup --backup-dir=`date +%Y.%m.%d` dev@10.10.10.10:test_repos/* source/backup
```

However, this will only do a incremental backup of the files changed. However, I want to do a full-back up with a new directory of the date that the backup was run.

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/).  It doesn't name the directories by date, but it'll do everything else you're after.